# Android Camera2 : can't take picture with front camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm currently working with [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), this sample is designed to take pictures with back camera, and it work's fine but when I changed this [line](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L501) to this :

```
if (facing != null && facing != CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
```

the preview is showing the facing camera as expected but it does't take pictures when I click picture button.

Why is this happening did I need to change something else ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved the issue by replacing this code in lockFocus ()

```
mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),mCaptureCallback,
mBackgroundHandler);
```

instead this you should call captureStillPicture();

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you explain what's the difference between those 2 lines?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the current camera ID before taking pic

```
 if (cameraId.equals(CAMERA_FRONT, false)) {
                    captureStillPicture()
                } else if (cameraId.equals(CAMERA_BACK, false)) {
                    lockFocus()
                }
```

ie for Front call this `captureStillPicture()`

else call this `lockFocus()`

**this happens because for focus problem in some phone with the front camera**